# Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float when I try to fetch Data from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I have trouble with getting data from Firebase. I try to fetch Data from firebase. 
Everything is fine, except for these two lines.

```
 func calculateDailyAmountOfCalories() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").child(uid!).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        self.userWeight = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "weight").value as!  Float
        self.userHeight = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "height").value as! Float
        self.userAge = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "age").value as! Float
        **var newUserGoal = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "userGoal").value as? Float
        var newUserLevelActivity = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "activityLevel").value as? Float**
        print(newUserGoal)
        print(newUserLevelActivity)



        print(self.userWeight)
        print(self.userHeight)
    }
}
```

When I try to fetch (var newUserGoal and newUserLevelActivity) `data without as?/! Float` I can see an answear in my terminel Optional(0.2) for example. When I try to use `as?` I get nil. 
why other similar snapshot work, but these not ?

Comment: try `Double` ...

Comment: Try: `self.userWeight = (snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "weight").value as!  NSNumber).floatValue`

Comment: @vacawama Thank you! :)